# alertmanager unsee behind nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to serve `alertmanager` and `unsee` from the same container.

In my testing:

I background `alertmanager`

I background `unsee`

I run /sbin/nginx

when I visit / I can see alertmanager

when I visit /unsee I get `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE`

I can curl http://127.0.0.1:8080 and see that unsee is serving files

I have the below config in `/etc/nginx/sites-enable`

```
server {
    listen 9093;

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9094;
    proxy_redirect off;

    # Socket.IO Support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}

location /unsee/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_redirect off;

    # Socket.IO Support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the configuration should be like this ...

```
server {
listen       9093;
server_name  alertmanager.*;

location / {
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;

    set $target http://container_hostname:9094;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass $target;
}
}

server {
listen       9093;
server_name  unsee.*;

location / {
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;

    set $target http://container_hostname:8080;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass $target;
}
}
```